# Kafka Consumer poll() returns empty set when used inside while loop

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a basic implementation of a Kafka Consumer. I have it working properly when it is calling the **`poll()`** method on button click (let's call this **V1**).

But as soon as I place the **`poll()`** method inside a **`while`** loop (let's call this **V2**), I stop receiving the messages.

The weird thing is that **V1** is still able to pick up the new messages but **V2** still receives an empty `ConsumerRecords` object.

I have made sure that **V1** and **V2** are in different **`ConsumerGroups`**.

Here, **V2** contains the code as shown below.

And **V1** has the **`while`** loop removed. Otherwise there is **no** other point of difference.

**Can someone tell me what is happening and why?**

**Code Reproduced below:**

```
btnButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0){
         while(true) {
             ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumerGroupObj.consumerObj.poll(100);

             // Trying to insert into DefaultTableModel here for an existing jTable

             // Some other processing code
         }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I noticed something here. It might not be the **`poll()`** method that is causing this. But the enclosing **eventHandler**. Please check the code provided above for updates.

What I've noticed is that, until the control exits this **`mouseClicked()`** method, the changes made by the code inside are not visible in the GUI.

So, my new question: **How do I make a Kafka consumer run in an infinite loop that is started by a button click event?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out *(through a very convoluted search)* that you **cannot** have a loop inside an event listener, for reasons that seem very obvious now.

That being said, I did find out that I can use a class that extends the `SwingWorker` class.

So basically, what I did was remove all the code from the `mouseClicked()` method and put it in the `doInBackground()` method of my `SwingWorker` class. Obviously, this created a lot of errors.

To troubleshoot those errors, I needed to pass all the information I needed from the GUI components to the `SwingWorker` class. I did this by using a **parameterised constructor**.

After that, I just instantiated the `SwingWorker` class with the proper values and executed the object. ***Et Voila!***

Answer (score 0):

Empty results may caused by short timeout parameter, you could try to increase it.

> timeout - The time, in milliseconds, spent waiting in poll if data is
>   not available in the buffer.

Comment: I've added a timeout of my own outside the timeout used in `poll()`. Also, increased and decreased the timeout used by `poll()`, ranging from 100ms to 5000ms. No effect. I do think it has something to do with the flow of control through the event handler.